# Merge SQL Data in Row, HTML Table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am trying to merge data in row on the basis of date, but I got this

[image]

I need the result like this

[image]

The columns are generating dynamically. This is logic I tried. Please guide me. Thank you.

```
var vHtml = '<table id="example_Day" class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">';
vHtml += '<thead>';
vHtml += '<tr id="rowDay">';
vHtml += '<th>Date</th>';
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    ProductArray.push(Returndata[i]["ShortCode"]);
    DateArray.push(Returndata[i]["DemandDate"]);
    MedIDArray.push(Returndata[i]["MedicineID"]);
}
ProductArray = ProductArray.filter(onlyUnique);
for (var i = 0; i < ProductArray.length; i++) {
    vHtml += '<th>' + ProductArray[i] + '</th>';
}
vHtml += '<th>Paid / Free</th>';
vHtml += '</tr>';
vHtml += '</thead>';
vHtml += '<tbody>';
DateArray = DateArray.filter(onlyUnique);
MedIDArray = MedIDArray.filter(onlyUnique);

for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    vHtml += '<tr>';
    vHtml += '<td>' + Returndata[j]["DemandDate"] + '</td>';

    for (var i = 0; i < MedIDArray.length; i++) {
        if (MedIDArray[i] == Returndata[j]["MedicineID"]){
            vHtml += '<td>' + Returndata[j]["Amount"] + '</td>';
        }
        else
        {
            vHtml += '<td> - </td>';
        }
    }
    vHtml += '<td>' + Returndata[j]["FreeOrPaid"] + '</td>';
    vHtml += '</tr>';
}



vHtml += '</tbody>';
vHtml += '</table>';

$('#table_day').html(vHtml);
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bCMc.jpg):

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqj4W.jpg):

Comment: Seems like you're outputting a row (`tr`) for each element in `Returndata`.

Comment: row is generating on the basis of the date, but I need only 1 date data in one row if possible, if not in jquery can you give me an example using c#

Comment: Since it seems you want one HTML row per date and you've made `DateArray` an array of unique dates... have you tried iterating over `DateArray` instead?

Comment: I solved this using C# by generating HTML from function, did some work on datatable filter. In jQuery(Yes, I Iterated with the condition of the same product id and date but haven't solved the problem until using C#).